# image background instead of button for dropdown

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I already have a `dropdown` with the following code:

note: `class='bg_r'` is in CSS for the background image (url) globe

```
<span class="bg_r">     
           
    Language: <a id="Lang" href="#">DropUp▲</a>
</span>
                <div id="language_menu" class="lang_switch_panel">
                    <div class="lang_switch">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The output for above code is as shown in figure 1 below:

[image]

Now, I'm doing similar to that(above figure) using `bootstrap 4`.But i'm not able to override the button style using background image.Instead of button type I replaced with `anchor tag` but of no use(its wrong method but i tried).
Following is the code I tried so far:

```
<span class="bg_r">
                 Language:
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropup
                  </button>
            </span>
             <!--<span class="bg_r">Language:
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropup
              </a>
            </span>-->
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>               
            </div>
```

The output for the code using bootstrap is as shown in figure 2 below:

[image]

How can I override button type with (background) image to get output similar to figure 1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it solve your issue ? or need some other help ?

Comment: just kept button style as '''background:none"...it works fine.thank you.@nan

Comment: Ok sure, but bg-transparent utility class of bootstrap does the same, no need to adding extra CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `btn-link` class to button

Additionally add these styles to center align it

```
.bg_r {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

or add these 2 classes  `d-inline-flex align-items-center` to `bg_r` span

```css
.bg_r {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="bg_r d-inline-flex align-items-center p-1">
             Language:
             <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropup
              </button>
        </span>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
</div>
```

You can also use `bg-transparent` on the button that will remove the background-color from button, but will not remove the focus styles when you click on the button ! So preferably add `btn-link` class to it only.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works, or you can also replace this line

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropup</button>
```

by

```
<a href="" class="btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropup</a>
```